# About Paypal recurring payment

Tags: paypal-sandbox

i have implemented paypal recurring payment through form api using sandbox

```html
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="codetestml003-facilitator@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/x-click-but20.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
</form>
```

the code was working properly. But now after login to paypal with buyer account the page is redirecting to my account page instead of payment procedure. Can anyone help?

Comment: I did implement the same recently and can help you but the question is not clear and I am not sure about how you implemented it, the code in your post is just a html form and nothing much. first the form can be edited in client side after `inspect element` and value can be made to `0` and second do give some clarification about your question

Comment: Previously with this form only the whole process is done. But now after i login with paypal it redirects to sandbox's my account page. So i cant proceed furthermore....or can u provide any help with paypal recurring subscription

Comment: There will be things like creating a plan and creating an agreement and after you get users consent on successful paypal transaction (you have to provide a callback url that paypal calls when success happens). you have to execute that agreement to start recurring payments, there are things to remember like agreement start date can only be after today.

Try reading into paypal rest api or atleast frontend implementation. you will need to have some code, mostly a lot more than this simple form to create plan, create agreement, on success callback, execute agreement, and yes read about IPNs too

Comment: basically i am using paypal subscribing form and after the process of checkout it should redirect to sandbox.paypal.com for further process but it’s redirect to ‘sandbox3.paypal.com’ and after login it goes to home page of paypal buyer sandbox. before 1 month it was working and i havn't change nothing in the code..so it's a bit strange..can't get any solution

Comment: Please check this link..this code is actually i am using https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/html_example_subscribe/